# TypeScript reports non-existent properties in generic function

Tags: generics, typescript

Consider the following generic function in TypeScript:

```
interface Foo { id: string; }
const foo = <Foo>{id: 'bar'};
function baz<T>(x: T) { console.log(x.id); }
baz(foo);
```

This doesn't compile:

> `test.ts(6,17): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'.`

It seems to me that TypeScript ought to be able to deal with this situation. If it can't, then I have to do something like this:

```
interface IHasId { id: string; }
interface Foo extends IHasId { }
const foo = <Foo>{id: 'bar'};
function baz<T>(x: IHasId) { console.log(x.id); }
baz<Foo>(foo);
```

Is there any alternative or more idiomatic way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Use `any` instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It makes sense, that first sample doesn't compile. Typescript is all about adding type checking.If you want to disable it you could use `any`, but why use generics in this case?

If you want to define constraint on generic type, you can do it this way:

```
function baz<T extends IHasId>(x: T) { console.log(x.id); }
```

By the way, constraint can be defined inline:

```
function baz<T extends { id: string; }>(x: T) { console.log(x.id); }
```